# No suitable driver found for {mysql.url} driver already declared in jpa

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-4

I had already declared my driver in my `jpa` class and also the dependecy for the connector for mysql and have the define schema in my DB.
but when am crating the war then message showing in logs the driver is loaded but when am class the api it is showing no suitable driver is find for {MySql}

> Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started Refreshing Root
>   WebApplicationContext: startup date [Mon Sep 02 10:58:58 IST 2019];
>   root of context hierarchy Registering annotated classes: [class
>   com.ghumapp.config.ApplicationConfig] JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject'
>   annotation found and supported for autowiring Bean 'applicationConfig'
>   of type [class
>   com.ghumapp.config.ApplicationConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c8072be1]
>   is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for
>   example: not eligible for auto-proxying) Loaded JDBC driver:
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory
>   for persistence unit 'default' Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory
>   for persistence unit 'default' Mapped "{[/getCity],methods=[GET]}"
>   onto public java.util.List
>   com.ghumapp.services.CityServices.saveCityData() Looking for
>   @ControllerAdvice: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Mon Sep
>   02 10:58:58 IST 2019]; root of context hierarchy Root
>   WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1330 ms
>   FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization started Refreshing
>   WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date
>   [Mon Sep 02 10:58:59 IST 2019]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
>   Registering annotated classes: [class com.ghumapp.config.WebConfig]
>   JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for
>   autowiring Mapped "{[/getCity],methods=[GET]}" onto public
>   java.util.List
>   com.ghumapp.services.CityServices.saveCityData() Looking for
>   @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace
>   'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Mon Sep 02 10:58:59 IST 2019];
>   parent: Root WebApplicationContext FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher':
>   initialization completed in 124 ms 02-Sep-2019 10:59:00.017 INFO
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web
>   application archive
>   [/home/yash/Downloads/apache-tomcat-9.0.22/webapps/ghumapp.war] has
>   finished in [2,219] ms Hibernate: select cities0_.id as id1_0_0_,
>   cities0_. name  as column2_0_0_, cities0_.Dist as Dist3_0_0_,
>   cities0_.population as populati4_0_0_ from cities cities0_ where
>   cities0_.id=? No suitable driver found for {mysql.url}

logs whic is comming in my apache server

```
@Value("${mysql.user}")
private String dbUserName;

@Value("${mysql.password}")
private String dbPassword;

@Value("${mysql.url}")
private String mysqlUrl;


public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(dataSource());
    em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.app" });

    JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
    return em;
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl(mysqlUrl);
    dataSource.setUsername(dbUserName);
    dataSource.setPassword(dbPassword);
    return dataSource;
}
```

Comment: You are using a placeholder and nothing is resolving the placeholders.

Comment: am not understand what you said. can you plz suggest me a better solution for this error

Comment: You probably have `@Value(${mysql.url} on your `mysqlUrl` field and apparently there is nothing replacing the `@Value` hence you don't have a placeholder configured in your application.

Comment: @Value("{mysql.user}")
 private String dbUserName;
 
 @Value("{mysql.password}")
 private String dbPassword;
 
 @Value("{mysql.url}")
 private String mysqlUrl;

Comment: They should have a leading `$` to be processed by Spring (as mentioned in the answer, below).

Comment: i did the same but still getting same error.

Comment: Then your values, aren't replaced and judging by your comment on the answer that you don't have t he proper driver included in your artifact.

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>mysql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
   <version>8.0.14</version>
  </dependency>
included like that in my pom.xml is anything more which i forget to mention or i mistakenly did???

Comment: Please don't add code as comments, that becomes quite unreadable, instead edit your answer.

Comment: ok ,do you have any solution for that i had tried the saveral ways for that but still same and dont know now what i have to do facing this problem from one week.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `mysqlUrl` value is not correct and it's value does not loaded from properties file. For example, this:

```
@Value("{mysql.url}")
private String mysqlUrl;
```

should be changed to this (consider `$`):

```
@Value("${mysql.url}")
private String mysqlUrl;
```

Comment: @Value("{mysql.user}")
 private String dbUserName;
 
 @Value("{mysql.password}")
 private String dbPassword;
 
 @Value("{mysql.url}")
 private String mysqlUrl;
                                                                                                                                               i have defined the values like that

Comment: It needs `$` before `{...}` to make Spring evaluate its value.

Comment: Hibernate: select cities0_.id as id1_0_0_, cities0_. name  as column2_0_0_, cities0_.Dist as Dist3_0_0_, cities0_.population as populati4_0_0_ from cities cities0_ where cities0_.id=?
No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/ghumapp
(now i hard coded the url values but still getting same

Comment: Maybe adding `:` after mysql helps. Like this: jdbc:mysql`:`//localhost:3306/ghumapp